# Implement Meta Conversation Api using Laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Meta Conversation Api to track Purchase Event on my site (build on Laravel).
This method that I use return me an error:

> "WWW-Authenticate" => array:1 [▶
> 0 => "OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Unsupported post request. Object with ID {$recipientId} does not exist, cannot be
> loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
> Please read the Graph API documentation at
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api" ◀OAuth "Facebook
> Platform" "invalid_request" "Unsupported post request.

```
public function setupPurchaseEvent($order)
{
    if(!$order)
    {
        return;
    }

    $recipientId = 9999999;

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $recipientId = Auth::user()->id;
    }
    
    $accessToken = env('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN');
    $purchaseData = [
        'event' => 'purchase',
        'recipient' => ['id' => $recipientId],
        'purchase' => [
            'purchase_type' => 'onetime',
            'purchase_data' => [
                'currency' => 'EUR',
                'value' => $order->price,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $response = Http::post("https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/$recipientId/events?access_token=" . $accessToken, $purchaseData);
    
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Most likely your access token doesn't contain all required permissions.

Comment: `$recipientId = 9999999;` You're using a real ID, right?

Comment: can you supply a link to the documentation for the endpoint you are using?